# How to wait for StatefulSet using Ansible's community.kubernetes.k8s_info module

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, kubernetes-statefulset

Ansible has a great `community.kubernetes` module.
One of the useful flags of `k8s_info` is [wait](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/kubernetes/k8s_info_module.html#parameter-wait) that is implemented for `Deployment`, `DaemonSet` and `Pod`.

For other k8s `kind`s it will return instantly unless `wait_condition` is provided.
What `wait_condition` should be provided to wait for `StatefulSet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using an "helper" tasks file. Say I have some `roles/commes/tasks/helpers/wait-for.yaml`, that goes something like this:

```
- name: "Waits for {{ obj_name }} to startup"
  block:     
  - name: "Checks latest {{ obj_name }} status" 
    debug:   
       msg: |    
         Object Kind {{ check_with.kind | default('nothing returned') }}                
    delay: "{{ wait_for | default(10) }}"
    ignore_errors: True
    retries: "{{ retries_for | default(10) }}"
    until:   
    - >          
        check_with.status is defined
        and check_with.kind is defined
        and check_with.status is defined
        and ((check_with.kind == 'Pod'
              and (check_with.status.containerStatuses[0].ready | default(False)))
             or (check_with.kind == 'DataVolume'
                 and (check_with.status.phase | default(False)) == 'Succeeded')
             or (check_with.kind in [ 'Deployment', 'DeploymentConfig' ]
                 and (check_with.status.availableReplicas | default(0)) >= 1)
             or (check_with.kind == 'Job'
                 and check_with.status.completionTime is defined
                 and check_with.status.succeeded is defined)
             or (check_with.kind == 'PersistentVolumeClaim'
                 and (check_with.status.phase | default(False)) == 'Bound')
             or (check_with.kind == 'StatefulSet'
                 and (check_with.status.readyReplicas | default(0)) >= 1))
```

Then, whenever I need to wait for a Kubernetes resource, I would include that tasks file, using:

```
- include_role:
    name: commons
    tasks_from: helpers/wait-for.yaml
  vars:
    check_with: "{{ lookup('k8s', api_version='apps/v1',
                           kind='StatefulSet', namespace='default',
                           resource_name='my-statefulset') }}"
    obj_name: "Statefulset default/my-statefulset"
    retries_for: 30
    wait_for: 10
```